# mysql join query with encrypted columns not decrypting or grouping

Tags: mysql

I have a query on a table with some encrypted fields like so:

```
SELECT groups.`group_id` AS id, `description_s`, 
  AES_DECRYPT(`description_l`, 'decryption_key') AS `description`, 
  AES_DECRYPT(groups.`email`, 'decryption_key') AS email,
  ...
FROM groups
WHERE ...
GROUP BY `id`, `description_s`,`description`,`email`,...
ORDER BY id DESC
```

This works as expected, giving me the decrypted output. However if I add a join to another table.

```
SELECT groups.`group_id` AS id, `description_s`, 
  AES_DECRYPT(`description_l`, 'decryption_key') AS `description`, 
  ...
FROM groups
INNER JOIN details on details.`group_id` = groups.`group_id`
WHERE ...
GROUP BY `id`, `description_s`,`description`,`email`,`customer_name`
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The result columns are no longer decrypted and the grouping only works if I put the AES_DECRYPT(`description_l`,dec_key) rather than the alias `description` in the 'group by' clause. Still leaving me with encrypted columns.

I found a workaround by using subqueries, and doing the decryption on the outside.

```
SELECT id,description_s, AES_DECRYPT(`description_l`,  'decryption_key') as description
FROM (
   SELECT groups.`group_id` as id, `description_s`, `description_l`
   FROM groups
   INNER JOIN details ON details.`group_id`=groups.`group_id`
   WHERE ... 
   GROUP BY `id`, `description_s`,description_l
) subq
ORDER BY id DESC
```

I am curious to know what exactly is going on. Why does the column not get decrypted at all in the second example above? Is there a way to get the grouped,decrypted result without using subqueries?

Comment: Firstly, what is your motivation for performing encryption in the database?  Are you aware that (in most cases) it provides very little security whatsoever, since plaintext is sent to/from the RDBMS together with the decryption keys?  Compromised RDBMS = game over.  Compromised application server = game over.  The only protection is against at-rest attacks where the key is unavailable, but it's probably lying around on the same machine somewhere, either in memory or in logs or elsewhere on the disk (such as the file in which you're storing it).

Comment: Secondly, it [works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a57438/1) - can you update the fiddle to exhibit your problem?

Comment: Not my idea, unfortunately I am working with a legacy db. I am aware that the encryption key gets sent with every query and is probably all over the logs. I looked at the fiddle, and was surprised to see it working. But I eventually figured out that the field definition was different (I have 'blob' instead of 'varbinary'). I changed the fiddle to be blob, and although the behaviour is still not exactly the same as mine (grouping still works) the description fields are now no longer decrypted in the second query. So I guess there's my answer... blobs are bad?

Comment: When I change `VARBINARY` TO `BLOB`, the only difference is that the resulting`description` column in the second query is a binary string whereas it is otherwise a character string.  Without investigating further, it could be a bug - albeit relatively minor as the returned data is nevertheless correct.

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33658/2 ), the fields are displayed correctly with the first query, but as a binary string in the second. As you say, they are decrypted after all, but I didn't realise this because phpmyadmin just displayed [blob] which it also displays for the encrypted fields, whereas it displays the string if it has been decrypted, or so I thought.

Comment: I suppose, if one thinks about it, there's no way for `AES_DECRYPT()` to know in what character set decrypted data should be returned; therefore it makes sense that it's a binary string.  I don't know why your first/unjoined queries return character strings.  You can use [`CONVERT(... USING ...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cast-functions.html) to explicitly return the resulting binary string in the appropriate character set.